# Set a callback for Google/Apple IAP

Tags: in-app-purchase, applepay

I'm trying to set in-app purchases for my app via IAP (. Checking the developer API I couldn't find a way to introduce a callback to be invoked as part of the payment processing.
I'm looking to have my own logic to allow / disallow the payment regardless of whether is it authorized by Google. Same thing for Apple actually.
For several reasons, I need to avoid doing these checks post payment.

Comment: Both, Google Pay and Apple Pay only return a token. No authorization takes place. You can add your logic in the "success callback" after you received a token. As long as you are not forwarding the token by calling your PSPs authorization API your customer does not get charged.

Comment: thanks! Do you know where in the IAP documentation I can find this callback? couldn't see something about it

Comment: So is this about IAP or Google Pay?

Comment: sorry, this is for IAP